# angular bootstrap ui modal does not display

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I use https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal , but my modal doesn't show up, only a tiny line of it. here is the image: [image]

here is my js:

```js
app.controller('PersonListController', ['$scope','ContactService','$uibModal', function($scope,ContactService,$uibModal){



  $scope.showCreateModal =function () {

      $scope.createModal = $uibModal.open({
          templateUrl: '../contact-app/templates/modal.create.tpl.html',
          bindToController: true,
          size: 'lg'
          });
  };



}]);
```

html: '../contact-app/templates/modal.create.tpl.html' -   works when I inspect the page its there but invisable

```html
<div class="modal fade" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Title</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
    <ng-include src="'templates/form.html'"></ng-include>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

when I use regular bootstrap modal it works , but when I use angular way it doesn't, please help!

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: no, no errors in console

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to use relative urls for your template?  You should be using the following approach instead:

In your html:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="modal.create.tpl.html">
  <div>
    Modal content
  </div>
</script>
```

Angular will then load the template into the template cache and you reference it is as:

```
templateUrl: 'modal.create.tpl.html'
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get it working with these code:

```
  $scope.createModal = $uibModal.open({
      templateUrl: '../contact-app/templates/modal.create.tpl.html',
      bindToController: true,
      scope: $scope

      });
```

'../contact-app/templates/modal.create.tpl.html':

```
 <div class="modal-header" ng-controller="PersonListController">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

            <ng-include src="'templates/form.html'"></ng-include>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="ok()">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="close()">Save changes</button>
        </div>
```

still not sure was was causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `<base>` tag and points the path to under the sub directory?

If so, your relative path might be wrong.

For my case, I was using `<base>` tag that looks like this

```
<base href="http://abc.test.com/test/" />
```

with http://abc.text.com/test/pages/index.html (where I am on)

The template file was located

```
'c:/web/test/contact-app/templates/modal.create.tpl.html'
```

In this case the path of 'templateUrl' must be

```
  templateUrl: 'contact-app/templates/modal.create.tpl.html',
```

Because the relative path will start with

```
http://abc.test.com/test/
```

instead of

```
http://abc.text.com/test/pages/
```